# Connect one-hot-encoding to value in column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, one-hot-encoding

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 26.8 |
| B | 23.5 |
| C | 22.5 |
| A | 21.9 |
| B | 23.1 |
| C | 29.1 |

To this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26.8 | 23.5 | 22.5 |
| 21.9 | 23.1 | 29.1 |

Problem:
Create one-hot-encoded variables from column A, and then insert the corresponding value from column B into the ones (1) of the one-hot-encoded variables using SQL.

I have tried to to used PIVOT without success in SQL.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database

Comment: Can you show us your current PIVOT attempt.

Comment: Do you have other column by which you can order the rows, i.e. (in the output) how can you guarantee that A=26.8 will be in the first row and A=21.9 will be in the second row.

Comment: Hi, I have another column which I can use for ordering the rows. Thanks for the answers, they are really helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. In SQL (not just Oracle), a result set has a non-deterministic ordering and unless you have some data that will allow you to order the results and determine which `(A,B,C)` triplets of rows are related then it is impossible to determine which `A` is related to which `B`.

For example, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Column_A, Column_B) AS
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT 'A', 26.8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 23.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 22.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 21.9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 23.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 29.1 FROM DUAL
  )
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() -- Simulate non-deterministic order of result set.
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT A, B, C
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column_A ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(column_b) FOR column_a IN ('A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c)
)
```

May (randomly) output:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21.9 | 23.5 | 29.1 |
| 26.8 | 23.1 | 22.5 |

It is chance which data point ends up in which row.

---

Whereas, if you have something in the data set that determines the row:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Column_A, Column_B, Column_C) AS
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT 'A', 26.8, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 23.5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 22.5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 21.9, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 23.1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 29.1, 2 FROM DUAL
  )
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() -- Simulate non-deterministic order of result set.
```

Then:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(column_b) FOR column_a IN ('A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c)
)
```

Outputs:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26.8 | 23.5 | 22.5 |
| 21.9 | 23.1 | 29.1 |

and you get the expected answer.

---

You need to have that extra data to be able to correlate the data points into the correct row.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F-gIPCSr)